# Detect if caret is inside specific characters codemirror 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, codemirror

I am making a markdown editor with codemirror 6. It uses `katex` to display math formulas. i want to detect if a caret is inside a math block section, so for example:

```
# Markdown title
- item
- item

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n
$$
```

i want to detect when the user is editing this portion: `\sum_{k=1}^n`, so when they are, it will display a little toolbox with the math rendered.

I tried with this:

```
const { val, setVal, prev } = useContext(EditorContext)!;
  const onEdit = useCallback((v: string) => setVal(v), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let cm = ref.current;
    if (cm) {
      /* cm.view?.dispatch({
            changes: { from: 0, to: cm.state?.doc.length, insert: "a" }
          }); */
      let caret = cm.view?.state?.selection.main.head;

      var precedingText = val.substring(0, caret);
      var followingText = val.substring(caret!);

      var openingParenthesesIndex = precedingText.lastIndexOf("$$");
      var closingParenthesesIndex = followingText.indexOf("$$");

      if (
        openingParenthesesIndex !== -1 &&
        closingParenthesesIndex !== -1 &&
        openingParenthesesIndex < closingParenthesesIndex
      ) {
        console.log("in Math block");
      } else {
        console.log("not in math block");
      }
    }
  }, [val]);
```

but it says that i'm never in a mathblock, even when I am